# Determinant of the irreducible characters table of a finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

> Let $G$ be an abelian group, $|G|=n<\infty$. Let $\Phi$ be an irrep of G. Find the modul of determinant of the characters table.

Ther is answer in my book. It is  $n^{n/2}.$
If G is cyclic then irreducible characters table has following form
$$1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,1\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 1\,\,\,\,\,\, 1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ldots\,\,\,\, 1\\
1\,\,\,\,\,\xi\,\,\,\,\,\,\xi^2\, \,\,\,\,\xi^3 \,\,\,\,\ldots \, \xi^{n-1}\\
1\,\,\,\,\,\xi^2\,\,\,\,\xi^4\, \,\,\xi^6 \,\,\,\,\ldots \, \xi^{2n-2}\\
1\,\,\,\,\,\xi^3\,\,\,\,\,\,\xi^6\,\,\,\,\, \xi^9\,\,\, \ldots \, \xi^{3n-3}\\
\ldots\\
1\xi^{n-1}\xi^{2n-2}\xi^{3n-3} \ldots\xi^{(n-1)^2}\\$$
The Determinant of this characters table is  Vandermonde determinant.

I can use 
[Determinant of the character table of a finite group $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156110/determinant-of-the-character-table-of-a-finite-group-g) as G is abelian.

Is there other way for abelian?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the key is to use the Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated abelian groups to write $$G\cong\mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}_{n_k}.$$ Now, let $V$ be an irreducible representation of $G$. Since $G$ is abelian, $V$ is one-dimensional. Therefore, $V$ is an irreducible representation of each factor $\mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$ when the representation is restricted to the factor. So, the character $\chi_V$ is a sum of the characters of the irreducible representations one gets by restricting to each cyclic factor. Given what you know about what happens for cyclic groups, this should allow you to proceed.