# Determinant of Character table as a matrix

Tags: representation-theory

I'm studying for finals and came across this problem in a book.

Suppose $G$ is a finite group with conjugacy class representatives $g_1,...,g_k$ and character table $Z$. Consider $Z$ as a matrix. Then I want to show that $\det(Z)$ is either real or purely imaginary and that $$|\det(Z)|^2=\prod_{i=1}^k |C_G(g_i)|,$$ where $|C_G(g_i)|$ is the centralizer of $g_i$.

I am very lost as to how to approach this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156110/determinant-of-the-character-table-of-a-finite-group-g